# Count words in a Text and group by

Tags: python, csv, methods, group-by, count

My task is that I have to write a program in which I create a table in which I have two headers :

```
WORD     ||    FREQUENCY
```

All words have to be under the header WORD. The Frequency of these words have to be under the header FREQUENCY

I have created the table with the headers and all words are under the header word. My problem is counting these words.

Here my code:

```
newresult = result.split()
myFile = open('table.csv','w') 

with myFile:
 writer = csv.writer(myFile)
 writer.writerow(["WORD","FREQUENCY"])
 for t in newresult:
   writer.writerow({t})
```

The whole text is saved in newresult. Now i have to count these words.

An example how it looks now:

```
WORD                     FREQUENCY

Hello

my 

Name

is

John

Hello

Guys
```

I dont know how to count these words.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you simply haven't done that part

Comment: I know but I dont know how

Comment: Had some ideas? some code you tried that you can share?

Comment: I have tried it with count and group by but because I am new in Python i always get error messages. Also the code has to be general so i cant write all words in the method count so that it can count them

Comment: Then I'd recommend looking to e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F; this isn't a code writing service.

Comment: That's great that you encountered errors, so you can learn from them. But it is accepted to post your previous attempts and error messages. That way you will receive better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, you've already done `newresult = result.split()`, which splits the string `result` into a list of individual words. That's half the job right there. Now you just need to count each word.

First, take *just* the unique words. You can do this by making a *set*:

```
uniques = set(newresult)
```

Then, iterate through the uniques and look for how many times each one is represented in `newresult` by using `newresult.count()`:

```
...
for word in uniques:
    writer.writerow([word, newresult.count(word)])
```